# Partitioned view on large parent and child table with foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, database-partitioning, partitioned-view

How can I do partitioned view on SQL Server (Standard edition) on two tables with foreign key - parent and child 1TB each - without changing queries called from application, so that queries are not inefficient?

Here is the schema (simplified): ( or on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c831f))

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(`idProduct` int, 
 `DateProduced` datetime, 
 `productName` varchar(7), 
 `description` varchar(55),
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProduct`)
);

CREATE TABLE ProductPhoto
(`idProduct` int primary key,
 `Image` BLOB);


CREATE TABLE ProductExport
( `idExport` int primary key,
  `idProduct` int, 
 `TimeExported` datetime, 
 `quantity` int);

alter table ProductPhoto
add constraint fk1_Photo foreign key (`idProduct`) references Product(`idProduct`);

alter table ProductExport
add constraint fk1_Export foreign key (`idProduct`) references Product(`idProduct`);
```

Here are possibilities:

a) if I make partitioned view on table Product based on DateProduced (partitions would be by month each), I cannot search by table's primary key effectively (`SELECT * FROM Product WHERE idProduct=3` will search in all partitions of table Product).

b) if I make partitioned view on table Product based on idProduct, I cannot search by DateProduced effectively.

I have also problem how to make both tables partitioned.

Is it possible to somehow make a reasonable partitioned view with both tables, with no large changes for queries (search all product between dates, get product by productId), so that it wouldnt be too slow?

Comment: You tagged this with sql server but the syntax looks like mysql. Which one is it??

Comment: It is MSSQL Server, the syntax is just as a simplified scheme example.

Comment: Why are you wanting to partition this? What are you hoping to accomplish by partitioning? It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you for reaction, I've edited question to make it clearer.